# What is the significance of the symbol in Tanaka's eyes?

Tags: .hack

At the end of the *Thanatos Report* OVA (set after the events of the *.hack//Sekai no Mukou ni* movie) after Tanaka picks up a certain chip, a symbol appears in his eyes.

What is the significance of this symbol? What does it mean for Tanaka?

[image: The eyes have it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a "doubleware" crest, meaning that aside from Tokio (from *//Link* and *//Versus*) Tanaka is the only other doubleware revealed up until now.

Doubleware humans can withstand [Real Digitize](http://dothack.wikia.com/wiki/Real_Digitalize) themselves within the virtual world without worrying about "Outer Dependency Syndrome," the gradual erosion of their mind and digital body.